# Unity 3d Importing .png via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, import, assets

I have a problem. When I try to import texture via script to my assets, I get this error:

> Assertion failed: Assertion failed on expression:
>   '!(o->TestHideFlag(Object::kDontSaveInEditor) && (options &
>   kAllowDontSaveObjectsToBePersistent) == 0)' 
>   UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:CreateAsset(Object, String) 
>   Editor.TextureImportWindow:OnGUI() (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Editor/TextureImportWindow.cs:40) 
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

and this:

> Could not create texture from Assets/Textures/importedTexture13.png:
>   File could not be read  UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:CreateAsset(Object,
>   String)  Editor.TextureImportWindow:OnGUI() (at
>   Assets/Scripts/Editor/TextureImportWindow.cs:40) 
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

My code:

```
 public class TextureImportWindow : EditorWindow
 {
     [MenuItem("Window/Pixel Terrain/Import Texture")]
     public static void ShowWindow()
     {
         GetWindow<TextureImportWindow>("Import Texture");
     }

     private Texture2D _texture;
     private string _path;

     private void OnGUI()
     {
         if (GUILayout.Button("Select File"))
         {
             _path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Choose texture", "", "png");
             if (_path.Length != 0)
             {
                 var www = new WWW("file:///" + _path);
                 _texture = Texture2D.blackTexture;
                 www.LoadImageIntoTexture(_texture);
             }
         }

         if (_texture != null)
         {
             if (GUILayout.Button("Import"))
             {
                 if (!AssetDatabase.IsValidFolder("Assets/Textures"))
                 {
                     AssetDatabase.CreateFolder("Assets", "Textures");
                 }
                 AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(_texture, "Assets/Textures/importedTexture12.png");
                 AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
                 AssetDatabase.Refresh();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `AssetDatabase.CreateAsset` supports few extensions and png is not one of them. According to the doc, these are the supported formats:

- `.mat` for materials
- `.cubemap` for cubemaps
- `.GUISkin` for skins
- `.anim` for animations
- `.asset` for arbitrary other assets.)

PNG is not mentioned anywhere so you get error when you try to import it with that function. `AssetDatabase.ImportAsset` is more appropriate for this but since it requires a relative path, it won't work because you are using an absolute path provided from `EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel`.

To import png file into your project from `EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel`, just copy it to the destination with  `File.Copy` or `FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory`(Recommended) then call `AssetDatabase.Refresh()`.

Replace:

```
AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(_texture, "Assets/Textures/importedTexture12.png");
AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```

with:

```
FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory(_path, "Assets/Textures/importedTexture12.png");
AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```

Comment: Thanks :D I didn't realize that I can do it this simple way :)

Comment: @LeoNguyen Please create new question